# Core Data - Add object to a relationship without firing a fault

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ipad, core-data

When I try to add a new ManagedObject to an existing relationship of an entity using the Core Data generated method "addArticleObject", a fault is fired for the articles relationship. Is it possible to add an object to a relationship without causing a fault to fire for the existing objects in the relationship?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I'm understanding your question exactly, but if you modify your core data model, as long as you go on the simulator and delete your app, then rerun it (so it regenerates everything), then you should be fine. You also might have to delete and recreate your NSManagedObject classes, but that's a quick thing also.

Answer (score 0):

If you've altered the structure of your Core Data model, unless you've done so with a migration you'll need to clear the previous version from the Simulator and any handsets you're testing on.  The error which occurs if you don't isn't particularly helpful.

Use the 'Reset contents & settings' option in the Simulator, and delete and reinstall the app on a phone.  Simply rerunning the app isn't enough.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that it is not possible to add objects to a many-to-many inverse relationship in Core Data without having both objects in the relationship in memory. I'm sure there must be a good reason for that requirement, which I would like to know. This has however caused me to have to refactor the database and all associated code